# MvvmCross: Android layout binding string resource

Tags: mvvmcross

Is it possible?:

```
//...
local:MvxBind="Text Format('{0} {1}', Stock, @string/in_stock)"/>
//...
```

I want to construct a text value using my property from ViewModel and string resource from **strings.xml**, but the example above does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK it is not directly possible to bind to an Android string.

Working with Xamarin and Mvx you should use `resx` files to support internationalization (i18n).

You can easily access the `resx` file from a binding using an indexer on your ViewModel:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public string this[string key] => Strings.ResourceManager.GetString(key);
}
```

Then in your View you can use it like:

`local:MvxBind="Text Format('{0} {1}', Stock, [InStock])"`

---

There is another way to bind strings in `resx` files that is using the [ResxLocalization](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/resxlocalization) plugin and even though it does not support `Format` yet you can workaround it (you can check this issue [Feature request: Combine MvxLang with Format](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/2243) to keep track of this)

Basically, you create your `Strings.resx` file in your PCL/NetStandard/Shared project and register it:

`Mvx.RegisterSingleton(new MvxResxTextProvider(Strings.ResourceManager));`

Then in your base view model you need to implement this property so your views and viewmodels have access to i18n:

`public IMvxLanguageBinder TextSource => new MvxLanguageBinder("", GetType().Name);`

Finally in your view you can call it using:

`local:MvxLang="Text InStock"`

Pay attention that it is using `MvxLang` instead of `MvxBind`. BTW you can use both of them but if you use `Text` in `MvxLang` then don't use it in `MvxBind` because problems will arise.

Finally you can combine the plugin with the indexer to lower the coupling between the ViewModel and the `resx` files and workaround the support of `Format` in the binding like this (taken from the issue abovementioned):

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private IMvxTextProvider _textProvider;
    public BaseViewModel(IMvxTextProvider textProvider)
    {
        _textProvider = textProvider;
    }

    public string this[string key] => _textProvider.GetText("", "", key);
}
```

and in your view (because of `Format` we cannot use `MvxLang` here):

`local:MvxBind="Text Format('{0} {1}', Stock, [InStock])"`

HIH